# jquery Dialog open if recordset is empty?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, dialog, dreamweaver

I am trying to use a Dialog within my webpage. I have a recordset which returns a email address.

I would like for the Dialog only to open if the recordset is empty.

This is Script so fare

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
   autoOpen: false,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  });
  </script>


<div id="body">

 <% If Email.EOF And Email.BOF Then %>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Error No Email address found">
              <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span> Error, you don't have an email address linked to your account. </p>
              <p> You cannot request this report</b>. </p>
            </div>

 <% End If ' end Email.EOF And Email.BOF %>

</body>
```

Any help would be great..... PS. .. i'm doing this in dreamweaver (so noob)...

Comment: Could you describe the issue you are having? Is the dialog opening even if there is an email, are you never getting emails back, is the dialog never opening, something else?

Comment: My code i had used at the start was correct, found out that instead of a NULL being passed back when there was no Email address was infact a space ' ', and i was checking for Null's.. Updated all ' ' emails address to NULL and it works perfect,

Was wrecking me head.

Comment: @user3339240 Hi and welcome to SO. I'm glad you found an answer to your question could you please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). This practice is actively encourage plus it means the question won't show up in the unanswered list.

Comment: @user3339240 you also didn't post relevant code, looks like the problem was with the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above works correctly. The reason it was not working for me was because my sql script was returning a result when i expect it to return nothing.

When nothing was returned then my If statement worked correctly.

Here it is in full

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<%
Dim Recordset2
Dim Recordset2_cmd
Dim Recordset2_numRows

Set Recordset2_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Recordset2_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_----------_STRING
Recordset2_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email FROM dbo.tblusers WHERE UserName = ? AND   Email <> ''" 
Recordset2_cmd.Prepared = true
Recordset2_cmd.Parameters.Append Recordset2_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 200, 1, 50, Recordset2__varusername) ' adVarChar

Set Recordset2 = Recordset2_cmd.Execute
Recordset2_numRows = 0
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" >
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="../animated_favicon1.gif" >
<title>-------------------</title>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      minWidth: 400,
      closeOnEscape: false,
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: "#targetElement",
      buttons: 
      { 'Go Back': function() { 
         document.location = '/HeadOffice/HeadOfficeMenu.asp'; 
  }, 

      }
    });
  });
  </script>
<body>
<header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">
                   ---------- </p>
            </div>

</header>
    <div id="body">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
            <table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" onClick="history.go(-1)" value="Back" class="noprint" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
          <p>This Request will be proccessed nightly and emailed.</p>
          <% If Recordset2.EOF And Recordset2.BOF Then %>
            <div id="dialog-message" title="Error No Email address found">
              <p> Error, you don't have an email address linked to your account.<br />
Please contact ---------------------------- and request to have your email added. </p>
              <p> You cannot request this report. </p>
            </div>
            <% End If ' end Recordset2.EOF And Recordset2.BOF %>

      </section>
    </div>

<footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>------------------
                </p>
            </div>
      </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
<%
Recordset2.Close()
Set Recordset2 = Nothing
%>
```